# input with value dont allow to change itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, input

I have input, and inside of it I have `value={this.state.date}` I can't type in this input, when value is still there.

I tried to use second variable `this.state.subdate` to change it first, but this made no effect. I tried placeholder, but this property can't make needed stuff.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
Col,
Button,
FormGroup,
Input,
Popover, 
Row
 } from "reactstrap";
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';
import { spawn } from 'child_process';

let id = 0;
function idGen(){
    return 'ds_select_'+(id++)
}

export default class Datetime extends Component{

    state={
    date: new Date(),
    isOpen : false,
    hours : '',
    minutes : '',
    subdate : '',
    }

onChange(e){
    e.setHours(this.state.date.getHours())
    e.setMinutes(this.state.date.getMinutes())
    this.setState({ date : e })
    //this.props.onChange({name : this.props.name, value : this.dateMs(e)})
} 



constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.id = idGen();
}
componentDidMount(){
    var da = new Date()
    this.setState({date : da, hours : da.getHours(), minutes : da.getMinutes(), subdate : da })
}

close(){
    this.setState({isOpen : !this.state.isOpen})
}
render(){
    return(<>
        {this.renderInput()}
        {this.renderCalendar()}
    </>)
}
dateMs(date){
    return Date.parse(date)
}
renderInput(){
    return(
        <Input 
        onBlur={(e) => {console.log('blur',e.target.value);
        this.setState({date : new Date(this.state.subdate),
            hours : new Date(this.state.subdate).getHours(),
            minutes :new Date(this.state.subdate).getMinutes()})}} 
        onClick={() => this.setState({isOpen : !this.state.isOpen})} 
        id={this.id}  type="text" name="date" placeholder={this.state.subdate} value={this.state.date}
        onChange={ e => {this.setState({subdate : e.target.value},() => {console.log(this.state.subdate)})}}    />
    )
}

renderCalendar(){
    return(
        <Popover id={'_'+this.id} placement="bottom-start"  hideArrow offset={0} isOpen={this.state.isOpen} target={this.id} toggle={() =>this.close()}>
            <Row style={{display: 'inline-grid', gridTemplateColumns:'360px 250px'}} form>
                <Col md={12}>
                    <FormGroup style={{marginBottom:'0px'}}>
                        <Calendar
                            onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}
                            e={this.onChange}
                            value={this.state.date}
                        />
                    </FormGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col style={{gridColumnStart: 2}} md={10}>
                    <FormGroup row>
                        <Col sm={6}>
                            <Input valid={this.state.hours >= 0 && this.state.hours <= 23} id={this.id+'hours'}
                            style={{textAlign:'center'}} type='number' max='23' min='0' name='hours' id='hours' placeholder={23}
                            value={this.state.hours}
                            onChange={e => {
                                var dat = this.state.date;
                                dat.setHours(e.target.value);
                                this.setState({date : dat, hours : e.target.value, subdate : dat})
                            }} />
                        </Col>
                        <Col sm={6}>
                            <Input valid={this.state.minutes >= 0 && this.state.minutes <= 59} id={this.id+'minutes'}
                            style={{textAlign:'center'}} type='number' max='59' min='0' name='minutes' id='minutes'
                            placeholder={23} value={this.state.minutes}
                            onChange={e => {
                                var dat = this.state.date;
                                dat.setMinutes(e.target.value);
                                this.setState({date : dat, minutes : e.target.value, subdate : dat})
                            }} />
                        </Col>                  
                    </FormGroup>

                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Popover>
    )
}
}
```

probably it is easy questions, because I just need an input property, like value\placeholder, but with some other features, that allow it to be real (so I can edit this thing by keyboard) and changeable by `this.setState()`

My problems were

1. `value` and `onChange` variable should be equal
2. `value` and `onChange` variable should not be `new Date(e.target.value)`, because it not allow you to delete something from string, if you want to change it you should highlight a letter and print a substitute.
3. my aim was to send changes with `onBlur`, so inside it I'd just make `new Date(value)` from value I printed

Comment: Any change you could simplify the example you have posted? I guess, the input is your problem but it would be helpful if you only post the required example code instead of the whole file content. It also may help you if you remove all unrelated content from your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check my fiddle to know how to achieve real time date updates:

[Change Hour](https://jsfiddle.net/pkm470f3/)

You can change logic accordingly. But setting state must be follow by the method described in my fiddle.

Very basic rule of setting state for particular input is that `onChange` only affects to your input value when your `setting state` and `assigned value state` is same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I knew your solution, but (according to your variation), I dont want to have 2 inputs, One with value and one editable, I want only 1 input where:

1. The value is `this.state.date`
2. I can edit it
3. `onChange` in this input is changing this.state.date

I'll try your solution, I think it could help, thank you.

Comment: Yes I know that date value of first input is changing. I made it disable by thought you need something like this, and welcome.

Comment: yes, your solution is right, it was really a stupid question from me, sorry for worrying, and thank you